# Business Process Management and Bit Per Minute: both BPM tag?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, ambiguous-tags

Looking at the questions associated to the [bpm](/questions/tagged/bpm) tag, there are 2 topics actually:

- Business Process Management, which is associated to the tag
- Beats Per Minute, related to Music, songs, audio processing

How can it be corrected? Should it be flagged? Or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Beats Per Minute. But that sounds like a considerably useless tag, since it can't stand on its own. =)

Comment: Perhaps creating a tag for "audio-processing" ?

Comment: Like [tag:audio-processing]? =D

Comment: While we're at it, there's a metric ton of questions tagged [tag:audio] and [tag:processing]. Well. 26, anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry, my comments might come off as snarky or sarcastic. That wasn't my intention. But these tags already exist. =)

Comment: J. Steen, I looked first at audio related tags and didn't find this one. Perhaps, my question can be corrected: when someone is tagging BPM for audio processing questions, how can it be corrected? Should it be flagged? Or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easiest to just go through them all and retag the *Beats Per Minute* ones as something else like [audio-processing](/questions/tagged/audio-processing).

There aren't that many audio related ones, so it won't take long (just whipped 3 out).

Comment: How many are there ? I just did 3 as well

Comment: @AshRj, I just found 5 in the first 100, so if you did 3, then there are probably only 10 more or so.

Comment: Did a few more, now I'll hold off to not spam the active page too much.

Comment: Did 5 more. There are some left http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbpm%5D+audio+is%3Aquestion

Comment: As I am interested about BPM related stuff, I will try to keep an eye on new entries with this problem. Did you already changed the existing one, or should I do it too?

Comment: @ttoine, I'm not sure what you mean by "changed the existing one".  I'm glad you realize that fixing the old ones doesn't stop it from being used wrongly in the future.

Comment: @LanceRoberts do I have to look for old questions with the wrong use of BPM, or "Did a few more" means it is already done? And yes, I will try to care of the use of this tag in the future, thanks to your tag/rss feature.

Comment: @ttoine, I think most are done, but another set of eyes on it isn't a bad thing.

Comment: I just found 7 more; I think they're all done now.

Comment: @Wooble The [tag:bpm] tag needs to be removed and [tag:audio-processing] added. You seem to have left [tag:bpm] in some that you edited. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5128842/revisions

Comment: For heaven's sake people, tidy up other stuff while you're at it. That question is a complete mess, @AsheeshR.